# Ionic 2: EXCEPTION: No provider for NavController

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

i have a problem with my ionic 2/angular 2 app.

I got an app.ts where the hole "auth" part is implementet.

The code looks like this:

```
 import {Nav, Platform, Modal, ionicBootstrap} from "ionic-angular";
import {NavController} from "ionic-angular/index";
import {StatusBar} from "ionic-native";
import {Component, ViewChild} from "@angular/core";
import {AngularFire, FirebaseListObservable, FIREBASE_PROVIDERS, defaultFirebase} from "angularfire2";
import {HomePage} from "./pages/home/home";
import {AuthPage} from "./pages/auth/home/home";

@Component({
  templateUrl: "build/app.html",
})

class MyApp {
  @ViewChild(Nav) nav: Nav;

  authInfo: any;
  rootPage: any = HomePage;
  pages: Array<{title: string, component: any}>;

  constructor(private platform: Platform, private navCtrl: NavController, private af: AngularFire) {
    this.initializeApp();

    this.pages = [
      { title: "Home", component: HomePage }
    ];

  }

  initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    });
  }

  openPage(page) {
    this.nav.setRoot(page.component);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.af.auth.subscribe(data => {
      if (data) {
        this.authInfo = data;
      } else {
        this.authInfo = null;
        this.showLoginModal();
      }
    });
  }

  logout() {
    if (this.authInfo) {
      this.af.auth.logout();
      return;
    }
  }

  showLoginModal() {
    let loginPage = Modal.create(AuthPage);
    this.navCtrl.present(loginPage);
  }
}
```

But now, when i try to run the app i get this message:

```
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: No provider for NavController
```

Do you have any idea how to solve this problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 20):

**You can not inject a NavController in a Root component via a constructor**.

So, basically you can `not` do something like below:-

```
constructor(private nav: NavController){
}
```

This is how you can inject a NavController

```
@Controller({
  ....
})
class MyApp{
  @ViewChild('nav') nav: NavController;
  ....
  ....
  constructor(...){ // See, no NavController here
  }
  ....
}
```

And this is what Ionic docs has to say.

> What if you want to control navigation from your root app component? You can't inject NavController because any components that are navigation controllers are children of the root component so they aren't available to be injected.
>
> By adding a reference variable to the ion-nav, you can use @ViewChild to get an instance of the Nav component, which is a navigation controller (it extends NavController)

Answer (score 15):

You can't inject the `NavController` in your **Root Component** so you should remove it from that part of the code. Further information can be found **[here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/#navigating-from-the-root-component)**.

Please make sure you already have a reference variable in your `ion-nav`, like this (the `#myNav)`:

```
<ion-nav #myNav [root]="rootPage"></ion-nav>
```

And then you can get that reference by using `ViewChild`. You can then just navigate to another page, by using that property:

```
import { Nav, Platform, ... } from "ionic-angular";
// more imports...
// ...

@Component({
  templateUrl: "build/app.html"
})

class MyApp {
  @ViewChild('myNav') nav: NavController // <--- Reference to the Nav

  authInfo: any;
  rootPage: any = HomePage;
  pages: Array<{title: string, component: any}>;

  // Remove the "navCtrl: NavController" from the constructor, since
  // now your getting the reference from the view
  constructor(private platform: Platform, private af: AngularFire) {
    this.initializeApp();

    this.pages = [
      { title: "Home", component: HomePage }
    ];

  }

  // ...

  openPage(page) {
    // this.navCtrl.setRoot(page.component); <-- Wrong!
    this.nav.setRoot(page.component) // <-- Right! Use the this.nav property
  }

  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 8):

It's recommended you use `this.app.getActiveNavs()` in Ionic 3+ as getActiveNav() will be removed in the next major release, so your function can be written as:

```
showLoginModal() {
    let loginPage = Modal.create(AuthPage);
    this.getActiveNavs().slice(-1)[0].present(loginPage);
}
```

To push on the nav stack, you can just import the page (say `YourPage`) then:

```
this.getActiveNavs()[0].push(YourPage);
```

**Old behaviour, for Ionic 2, deprecated in Ionic 3:**

You can use `this.getActiveNav()` in Ionic 2 (and Ionic 3), so your function can be written as:

```
showLoginModal() {
    let loginPage = Modal.create(AuthPage);
    this.getActiveNav().present(loginPage);
}
```

With either method you don't need any `import` or `private` variable for this to work. If you're in a `Component`, just refer to your `App`:

```
import {App} from 'ionic-angular';
import {MyPage} from '../pages/my/page';

@Component()
export class MyComponent {
    constructor(private app: App) {
    }
    goToMyPage() {
        this.app.getActiveNav().push(MyPage);
    }
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Thanks @Adam, I've double post on two questions, so you're right, not really helpful here! I'm editing it right now.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, i just used the nav instead of NavigationController and now it works.

Answer (score 2):

I handled it with:

```
import { App, NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

constructor(protected app: App) {
... }

get navCtrl(): NavController {
    return this.app.getRootNav();
}
```

Answer taken from here: [github issues](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/9581)

Answer (score 1):

You named your nav incorrectly;

```
this.nav.setRoot(page.component);
```

Should be

```
this.navCtrl.setRoot(page.component);
```

And double check if your importing correctly

```
import { NavController} from 'ionic-angular';
```

Comment: This is not an error! `NavController` is correctly imported. The problem is that it cannot be injected here. He made a reference to `nav` by writing `@ViewChild(Nav) nav: Nav;`. `Nav` extends `NavController` so it can be used instead.

Answer (score 0):

One cause for this error is when you try to inject `NavController` into a provider class.
Like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class MyProviderService {

  constructor(private nav: NavController){
  }
}
```

I just had that error...
After removing this injection (and refactoring the code), it worked fine.