# ionicon exists in DOM but not visible (has 0px of width)

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionicons

I want to display an arrow to go back in one of my Page because I'm coming on this page without using navCtrl, from app.component.ts, as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38121961/ionic-2-exception-no-provider-for-navcontroller).

So when I'm coming on this page from app.component.ts, I'm setting a flag to true and having a condition in my template that display a col-1 with a backArrow inside and a click that brings to another page if this flag is set to true. But this arrow is never displayed. I checked on developer console in the DOM and the col-1 is present, but the arrow has a width of 0.

Here is the screen of the result:

[image]

Here's my header:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-row *ngIf="backArrow else elseBlock3">
        <ion-col col-1>
        <ion-buttons left>
          <button ion-button large (click)="goToChats()"><ion-icon name="arrow_back" style="font-size:32px;"></ion-icon></button>
        </ion-buttons>
      </ion-col>
        <ion-col col-10>
        <ion-title style="margin-left:30%;margin-top:-3.5%;">
          <img src="assets/imgs/masque.png" title="Masque Neemous" alt="Masque Neemous" style="margin-left: -2.5%;"><br />
          Chat
        </ion-title>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col col-1>
        <ion-buttons right>
          <button ion-button large style="margin-left:-180%;margin-top:20%;" (click)="showMenu()"><ion-icon name="menu" style="font-size:32px;"></ion-icon></button>
        </ion-buttons>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
    <ng-template #elseBlock3>
        <ion-row>
          <ion-col col-11>
            <ion-title style="margin-left:30%;margin-top:-3.5%;">
              <img src="assets/imgs/masque.png" title="Masque Neemous" alt="Masque Neemous" style="margin-left: -2.5%;"><br />
              Chat
            </ion-title>
          </ion-col>
          <ion-col col-1>
            <ion-buttons right>
              <button ion-button large style="margin-left:-180%;margin-top:20%;" (click)="showMenu()"><ion-icon name="menu" style="font-size:32px;"></ion-icon></button>
            </ion-buttons>
          </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
    </ng-template>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
```

I searched for hours in the internet but never found any related thread, I can't see what's causing this. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks to anyone who will read/answer this post.

Comment: Try changing `arrow_back` to `arrow-back` ;)

Comment: rofl this day killed me, thanks and sorry for this xD

Comment: no worries, we've all been there!

Comment: Thanks for your understanding <3